# Generating function, N coin tosses: Find the probability that the total number of heads is a) even b) divisible by 3.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

A biased coin showing heads with probability p ∈ (0, 1) is tossed n times. Find the probability that the total number of heads is a) even b) divisible by 3.

For the following solution I am confused about part b "identity we wrote is an equality for polynomials on R" what is the identity and what is the polynomial?

Secondly, "Since the identity we wrote is an equality for polynomials on R, it in fact holds for all complex numbers t" why does this imply that complex numbers t work as well?

Thirdly, i dont understand the root of unity part or how it is derived to $\frac {G(1) + G(ε) + G(ε^2)} 3$ part. Please explain thanks.

Solution. Let X be the number of heads. We have X ∼ Bin(n, p) and let us write its probability generating function G(t),
$G(t) = (1 − p + tp)^n = P (X = 0) + tP (X = 1) + t^2P (X = 2) + . . . + t^nP (X = n).$

a) We would like to find P (X is even) = P (X = 0) + P (X = 2) + . . .. We have
$$\frac {G(t) + G(−t)} 2 = P (X = 0) + t^2P (X = 2) + . . . $$
thus $$P (X is even) = \frac {G(t) + G(−t)} 2 =\frac {1+(1−2p)^n} 2$$

b) Since the identity we wrote is an equality for polynomials on R, it in fact holds for all complex numbers t. We would like to find P (3 divides X) = P (X = 0) + P (X = 3) + . . .. Let ε = $e^{2πi/3}$ be a third root of unity. Since $1^k + ε^k + (ε^2)^k$ is zero unless k is a multiple of 3, in which case it is 3, we get

$$\frac {G(1) + G(ε) + G(ε^2)} 3 = P (X = 0) + P (X = 3) + . . . .$$

Answer (score 2):

> *Ad:* For the following solution I am confused about part b "identity we wrote is an equality for polynomials on R" what is the identity and what is the polynomial?

The identity is
\begin{align*}
(1 - p + tp)^n = P (X = 0) + tP (X = 1) + t^2P (X = 2) + . . . + t^nP (X = n)\tag{1}
\end{align*}
where both sides represent a polynomial in $t$ having degree $n$ with equal coefficients.

> *Ad:* Secondly, "Since the identity we wrote is an equality for polynomials on R, it in fact holds for all complex numbers t" why does this imply that complex numbers t work as well?

This is due to the *[Identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)*. The polynomials  in (1) are holomorphic functions which are also defined on $\mathbb{C}$. Since left-hand side and right-hand side agree on $\mathbb{R}$ which is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ with accumulation points, the identity is valid in $\mathbb{C}$.

*Note:* Similarly we can show for instance that from the validity of the identity $\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ for $z\in\mathbb{R}$ the validity for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ follows. See *[this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344964/why-does-cosz-fraceize-iz2/2345001#2345001)* for more information.

> *Ad:* Thirdly, i dont understand the root of unity part or how it is derived to $\frac {G(1) + G(\varepsilon) + G(\varepsilon^2)}{3}$ part. Please explain thanks.

The $r$-th *[roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity)*  $\varepsilon_j=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ij}{r}\right), 0\leq j<r$ have the nice property to *filter* elements. For $r>0$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{r}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ij n}{r}\right)=
\begin{cases}
1&\qquad r\mid n\\
0& \qquad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

See *[this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747813/how-to-find-a-formula-for-a-periodic-sequence/1748011#1748011)* for some details and  *H.Wilf's* *[Generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf)* (2.4.4) - (2.4.9) for more information.

Comment: thanks a lot but i kind of missed your second point can you elaborate a little more? and so for third i can take that filter summation functino as a given identity?

Comment: @jamesblack: I've added some more infos and references. The third point needs familiarity with multiplication of complex numbers. The second point is somewhat more demanding, needing some basics from complex analysis.